# What should be the input to skimage.color.rgb2lab?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-image, srgb

I've been using linear rgb (no gamma correction) with rgb2lab. However I just noticed that rgb2lab is really rgb2xyz followed by xyz2lab, and that rgb2xyz **actually expects sRGB**. So it would seem that if I have an sRGB image with RGB in (0,255) I should pass image/255 to rgb2lab. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that no problem, but scikit-image will automatically convert the 0–255 range to 0.0–1.0. See [Image data types and what they mean](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/data_types.html) in our documentation for details.